# override function push in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala

The problem is from cracking-coding-interview, problem 3.2

> Stack Min: How would you design a stack which, in addition to push
>   and pop, has a function min which returns the minimum element? Push,
>   pop and min should all operate in 0(1) time.

Then I wrote the following code, but the push function is wrong, because the incompatible type, not sure the problem, and why the pop is correct? Thanks

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

class StackMin extends Stack[Int] {
  val minstack=new Stack[Int]

  override def push(element: Int): Stack[Int]={
    if (element<= min()){
      minstack.push(element)
    }
    super.push(element)
  }

  override def pop(): Int={
    val value=super.pop()
    if(value==min())
      minstack.pop()
    value
  }

  def min():Int={
    if(minstack.isEmpty)
      Int.MaxValue
    else minstack.top
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clever solution.

The return type of the `push` method is wrong. You can specify it as `StackMin.this.type`:

```
override def push(element: Int): StackMin.this.type = {
```

Or leave it out entirely (let the compiler infer it):

```
override def push(element: Int) = {
```

Comment: May I know what's the difference between StackMin.this.type and Stack[Int] :(, becasue StackMin.this.type is the subclass of Stack[Int], I thought should be correct, thanks :)

Comment: @sweetyBaby You are right, but you can't widen the return type of a method you override. You can only narrow it. See [Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @Odomontois "Compiler will resolve it to the most concrete known type of the current value." No, that's not what `this.type` means. It's the type which has `this` as its only instance (discounting `null`). E.g. `class X { def foo: this.type = new X }` isn't legal: `this.type` isn't getting resolved to `X` here!